# Implement Validators.required in a custom component

Tags: angular

Is there a way to create a custom component which can be validated with the built in `Validators.required`?
I solved the problem by creating a own required validator but it seems hacky...

Use case:
I have a custom typeahead component which I will be using in different forms and I want to use the built in required functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement typeahead component as custom `ControlValueAccessor` and required Validator will work.